Does the sanctuary spell save from an accidental attack?
If an ally makes an accidental attack does Sanctuary still apply? Since it wasn't a targeted attack, I assume it shouldn't, but what's the official ruling? In my game, due to a nat1 while trying to hit a swarm-type enemy that was all over a character protected by a Sanctuary spell, an ally accidentally attacked a character who was protected by a Sanctuary spell.

Homebrew problems require homebrew solutions.
Accidentally attacking an ally on a natural 1 attack roll is not an official rule of the game, it’s a house rule. Consequently, the official rules of the game don’t govern this house rule situation, so there is no rules-based answer here. It’s up to the DM to manage the consequences of any house rules they choose to use.
That said, to me it seems the flavor of sanctuary is preventing intentionally attacking, so at my table, I’d rule that it does not prevent accidents.

Could also be a point of note that, "This spell doesn't protect the warded creature from area effects..." So attacks that don't specifically target the warded person are, by the rules, allowed to cause damage. I'd say this also backs up your ruling.

There are two sides to this
Strictly by the rules
Looking at the spell, it states:

any creature who targets the warded creature with an attack

What you are describing is an attack dealt by one of the player characters to another player character. Every attack has a target, which is either a creature or an object. In this case the target is the PC that under the effect of Sanctuary, which, by the quote listed above makes the spell take effect and forces the attacker to make a wisdom saving throw, which will determine if it must choose a new target or not.
Though, we should go one step further
Accidental attacks are not part of the rules D&D 5e. What you are describing is a homebrew critical fumble system from your DM (or from yourself if you are the DM). And the problem you are having is a special, edge case of that homebrew system. Which means your GM needs to make a ruling on how this system interacts with this spell. Here are some possible solutions.

The accidental attacker needs to target a different creature, if it fails the save
The accidental attacker makes no save and attacks regardless of sanctuary
The accidental attacker can choose not to attack if it fails the save
The accidental attack makes no save and can automatically choose not to attack

Your GM should think all possible options through and decide what makes the most sense logical and more importantly, what is best for your group, i.e. which option will increase your group's enjoyment the most. This might even go so far as deciding to no longer use that critical fumble system anymore, if it seems to get in the way of you guys playing the game to the fullest.

Only you know
This is your homebrew rule, not the official rules. It's therefore impossible to have an official ruling. I think it's logical that Sanctuary does not protect when the attacker doesn't target the character with Sanctuary.

It depends on how your accidental attack rules are worded
RAW, there are no "accidental attacks".  A roll of 1N always misses:

If the d20 roll for an attack is a 1, the attack misses regardless of any modifiers or the target's AC.

Since "the attack misses" there is no chance for it to hit a collateral target.  The DMG has an optional rule for critical failures (p.242), but this is only for ability checks and saving throws, not for attack rolls.
Thus your accidental attack is a house rule.  So how is it worded?  Likely your DM has just declared it something that happens on a 1N, without putting it down in words.  But what happens in the case of sanctuary will actually depend on the precise wording, since sanctuary says (emphasis mine):

Until the spell ends, any creature who targets the warded creature with an attack or a harmful spell must first make a Wisdom saving throw. On a failed save, the creature must choose a new target or lose the attack or spell.

Note that for the sanctuary to have effect, the warded creature must have been targeted not just by the attack, but by the author of the attack.  Again, depending on how your accidental attack effect is worded it might, or might not, interact with this.  To illustrate, let's look at two effects that are RAW:
The enchantment school wizard's ability Instinctive Charm says (emphases mine):

...when a creature you can see within 30 feet of you makes an attack roll against you, you can use your reaction to divert the attack, provided that another creature is within the attack's range. The attacker must make a Wisdom saving throw against your wizard spell save DC. On a failed save, the attacker must target the creature that is closest to it, not including you or itself. If multiple creatures are closest, the attacker chooses which one to target.

In this case, the attacker potentially chooses a new target for their attack after an initial attack roll is made.  Since it is the attacker doing the targeting, a target protected by sanctuary would force a save on the new attack.  Thus, instinctive charm does trigger sanctuary.
On the other hand, consider the Goblin Boss' redirect attack ability:

When a creature the goblin can see targets it with an attack, the goblin chooses another goblin within 5 feet of it. The two goblins swap places, and the chosen goblin becomes the target instead.

Here, the attacker does not target the new goblin.  Rather, the attacker targeted the Goblin Boss, and then the Goblin Boss forced another goblin to become the target of the attack without the consent of the author of the attack.  In this case, sanctuary fails to trigger, because the "any creature who targets the warded creature with an attack" condition is not met.  If the secondary goblin was warded by sanctuary, it would not help them, because while they became the target of the attack, there was no creature who targeted them with an attack and no one to make the save.  Thus, redirect attack does not trigger sanctuary.
As can be seen, you will need to specify precisely how your accidental attack effect works in order to know whether it triggers sanctuary.

While technically probably correct, not many people actually write down homebrew rules in a way that should be rules lawyered, if at all.

@SeriousBri Which is what I was trying to get at when I said "Likely your DM has just declared it something that happens on a 1N, without putting it down in words."  And yet, OP has come here asking how it would work.  Thus my answer is "we can't tell you how it would work unless we know the actual wording, because that will affect whether sanctuary is triggered or not, and here are some examples why."
